# How set docker image timezone when create the service in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have an api image that runs on my docker containers. But I have a timezone problem. So when I run my container I run this command

```
docker run -d  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -p 80:80 <dockerhubname>/<image>:latest
```

And this command working very well. Right now I want to publish this image in docker swarm as a docker service but when I run this command :

```
docker service create --name web --publish=80:80 --constraint=node.role==worker --mount=/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro <dockerhubname>/<image>:latest
```

I get this error : invalid argument "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro" for "--mount" flag: invalid field '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro' must be a key=value pair.

So how can I run my docker image with the right timezone as docker service in docker swarm?

Comment: i might not of help with the other quest but did you try this? https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#data-volumes

Comment: Hi mate, i have already solved this problem by creating a stack yaml file and deployed that stack file when I create the services. Thank you for your attention :) @Isparia